# Is it possible to send an xpdf process a signal that causes it to reload the file being displayed?

Tags: command-line, pdf, signals, poppler

On page change, redraw, or Reload command, `xpdf` will reload the file it is currently displaying.  Is it possible to cause `xpdf` to reload the file by sending a signal?  Which signal?

(I am basically looking for the functionality offered by `xpdf -remote ServerName -reload`, except I want to apply it to an `xpdf` that was not launched with the `-remote` option.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use a signal. But Xpdf accepts synthetic events, so it's easy to programmatically type `r` into the window using `xdotool(1)`.  Unfortunately the `xpdf` window does not identify itself by its PID, but the following seems to work:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible  --class Xpdf key r
```

If you know the name of the file that Xpdf is displaying, you can match the window's title:

```
xdotool --name 'Xpdf: foo.pdf' key r
```

There's a small risk of a false positive with another window whose title just happens to contains that string. [Other window matching options](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#window_commands) may help pinpoint the right window.

Comment: Turns out xpdf doesn't post its PID, so `--pid` does not work.  But ` xdotool search --onlyvisible  --class Xpdf key r` works.  And thanks for telling me about `xdotool`!  Useful!